# If $gW$ is reducible, why is $g^{-1}(gW)=W$ also reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Consider $H \subset G$ a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $V$ be a finite dimensional complex representation of $G$. Then one can show, that if $W \subset V$ is an $H$-invariant subspace, so is $gW$ for any $g \in G$. Furthermore, if $W$ is irreducible for $H$ then so is $gW$ for any $g \in G$. I have the solution of this exercise, which is very much straight forward, but there is a particular part that bothers me, regarding the irreducibility. It states:

---

> Let $W$ be irreducible and $g \in G$. Assume now that $gW$ is reducible, then so is $g^{-1}(gW)=W$, contradicting the irreducibility of $W$. So $gW$ is irreducible.

---

So basically my **question** is: If $gW$ is reducible, why is $g^{-1}(gW)=W$ also reducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be irreducible and $g \in G$. Assume now that $gW$ is reducible. That means there exists a nontrivial sub-space $\tilde{W} \subset W$, s.t. $\forall h \in H: hg\tilde{W}=g\tilde{W}$

But that implies $\forall h \in H: h \tilde{W} = g^{-1} g h g^{-1} g \tilde{W} = g^{-1}((g h g^{-1}) g \tilde{W})=g^{-1}g\tilde{W}= \tilde{W}$

(We used that $ghg^{-1} \in H$ ). And thus $\tilde{W}$ is invariant which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $gW$ is reducible, write $gW=W'\oplus W''$ where $W'$ and $W''$ are nontrivial $H$-invariant subspaces. Then, $W = g^{-1}(gW) = g^{-1}(W')\oplus g^{-1}(W'')$ because $g$ acts as a linear isomorphism. In particular, the direct sum decomposition is still nontrivial. Meanwhile, $Hg^{-1}W' = g^{-1} HW' = g^{-1} W'$ by normality of $H$ in $G$. So, $g^{-1}W'$ and $g^{-1}W''$ are both $H$-invariant.